# Why am I getting a list error on a python list (recursion)?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I am trying to create custom permutations in a list (mainly to mess around with recursion in python).  Right now I get this error when I run my code:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Before I added in the list copying, I was getting this:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

```py
def findPermutations (size, max, curr_perm):
    if not curr_perm or len(curr_perm) < size:
        for i in range(1,max):
            new_arr = list(curr_perm)
            findPermutations(size, max, new_arr.append(i))
    else:
        return curr_perm


print(findPermutations(2,3,[]))
```

I was hoping to return a bunch or permutations.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `NoneType` means you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. In other languages known as `null`. Use a debugger and check the values.

Comment: `new_arr.append(i)` returns `None`. Append, then pass the list into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need append the item list before calling recursive function. Below is the working code, Please let me know if you have any questions, i would be very happy to help you out.

```
def findPermutations (size, max, curr_perm):
    if not curr_perm or len(curr_perm) < size:
        for i in range(1,max):
            new_arr = list(curr_perm)
            new_arr.append(i)
            print(new_arr)
            findPermutations(size, max, new_arr)
    else:
        return curr_perm
findPermutations(2,3,[])
```

```
**Result:**
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks!  First: can you explain why having it in the function call didn't work?  Second:  how do I get the function itself to return the lists; it still returns None?

Comment: Here two things we need to consider: The list.append function does not return any value(but None), it just add the value to the list you are using to call that method and other one is python lists runs asynchronously until we specify. so in your case when you call new_arr.append(i) in function call, by the time, it considers list is empty before executing append in function call.   For your second question, did you tried with my solution. I don't think you will see 'NONE' with my solution. let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  I have it working now, I didn't see that you had put in the print statement.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you it helped. Could you please mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your code:

```
    new_arr.append(i)
    findPermutations(size, max, new_arr)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Why do they need to be split up?

Answer (score 0):

The `list.append()` function returns `None`.

It does not return the new updated list. It simply modifies the existing list and returns `None`. Hence `None` is passed as the third parameter in the `findPermutations()` function in the subsequent recursive call.

The answer by @Wonka splits up the code into two parts. This allows the `new_arr` list to be updated first and then passed onto the function.

Using `new_arr + [i]` would be a better option here. This creates a new list and that is passed onto the next recursive function call.